# Typescript compiled JS works but ts-node-dev throws compilation errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc, ts-node, ts-node-dev

I am trying to use the npm package `fs-xattr` in a Typescript project but I cannot seem to get things working between both `tsc` and `ts-node-dev`.

When I run `npm run build && node index.js` it works fine. When I run `npm run dev` then it crashes with the error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /home/meme/xfs/node_modules/fs-xattr/index.js
```

What I would like to be able to use `ts-node-dev` while developing this, so however I can get both `tsc` and `ts-node-dev` to work correctly, including changing whatever JSON values or Node versions or whatever, no problem.

The simplest way to reproduce, running on Node 14.17.6 with these files:

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "xfs",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev index.ts",
    "build": "tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.9.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "fs-xattr": "^0.4.0"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": ["es2020"],
      "target": "es2020",
      "moduleResolution": "Node",
  
      "strict": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

**index.ts**

```js
import { getAttribute } from 'fs-xattr'

async function run() {
    console.log('RUN');
    const r = await getAttribute('/some/file.txt', 'whatever');
    console.log('>>>>', r);
}

run().catch(e => console.log(e));
```